# Can not use npm install in project

Tags: 18.04, nodejs, npm

I've installed node using nvm, but when I go in my project folder and try to run npm install it shows npm not found.

However I tried to install gulp globaly with sudo npm install -g gulp it worked.

When I use which npm it shows /home/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v14.13.1/bin/npm

How to overcome this and be able to use npm install inside my project folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you initiated the npm project, using `npm init`? To be able to install npm packages in a folder, there has to be an npm project present in that folder. (Also read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/development_environment to learn more about setting up npm)

Otherwise, could you try running `npm -v` and see what the output is?

Comment: I made mistake, not selecting the version of node via nvm. 
It works now, hopefully, it will stay that way.

Comment: Ah okay! I'm glad it's working for you now :)